# File Pathing problems in Java applet

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io, java-web-start, japplet

I am having issues with my java web start applet in netbeans. I cannot get the pathing right for files and images that need to be accessed by the applet from the place where it is run from (i.e the server). Basically I am using images on the local machine to display icons of folder and pdf files, this works all well and good when I run the applet in a non-web context, however attempting to use it in a server sense causes failure.

Here is the code causing problems:

```
company.readCompanyFile("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Desktop\\ArFile Clients\\" + companyName + "\\"
                    + companyName + ".cmp");
```

this is just a simple buffered reader attempting to read in files stored in this location. Is the problem that these directories should instead be nested within the programs root directory which is:

```
C:\Users\Chris\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ArFile
```

An example reflecting the information I have given above would be great

EDIT: Here is the error message that is given by the Applet

```
BadFieldException[ The field <extension>href has an invalid value: C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients,C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients]
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.getAttributeURL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.getRequiredURL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.handleResourceElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.access$800(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat$2$1.visitElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.visitChildrenElements(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat$2.visitElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.visitElements(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.buildResourcesDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptorFromCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptorFromCache(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error while initializing manager: BadFieldException[ The field <extension>href has an invalid value: C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients,C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients], bail out
BadFieldException[ The field <extension>href has an invalid value: C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients,C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients]
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.getAttributeURL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.getRequiredURL(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.handleResourceElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.access$800(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat$2$1.visitElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.visitChildrenElements(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat$2.visitElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLUtils.visitElements(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.buildResourcesDesc(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptorFromCache(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptorFromCache(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.initialize(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.initManager(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain.access$200(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginMain$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Error while initializing manager: BadFieldException[ The field <extension>href has an invalid value: C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients,C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ArFile Clients], bail out
```

Comment: Have you setup the security stuff to allow the applet to access local resources?

Comment: as in signing? I have set the applet to be signed

Comment: i think i may have solved the issue, the .jlnp file that was being generated was adding a single reference that doesnt exist, after removing this my app compiled and ran, now it has an entirely different problem but ill tinker with it first before posting again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using relative file pathing, this does not work in a Java Web Start context, Absolute pathing must be used in order for the application to function.